# Dependency Injection in Node with many imports

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection

I'm trying to figure out where dependency injection has it's place in Node. I can't seem to get my head around it even though I know how it works in Java and I've been reading countless blogs.

The examples on the net imo are to *trivial*. they don't really show Why DI is needed. I'd prefer a complicated example.

I've looked at the following frameworks:

https://github.com/young-steveo/bottlejs

http://inversify.io/

Now, Node uses the module pattern. When I do an import it receives a singleton since that's what node does, it caches modules, unless the factory pattern is used to return a new instance (return new MyThing()).

Now dependency injections primary function is to decouple everything.

When people say that, I get the notion that the goal is... To remove *all* the imports from the top of a module.

How I write today:

```
'use strict';

// node modules
import os from 'os';
...8 more modules here
import fs from 'fs';
// npm modules
import express from 'express';
...8 more modules here
import _ from 'lodash';
// local modules
import moduleOne from './moduleOne';
...8 more modules here
import moduleTen from './moduleTen';

//...rest of my code
```

Having 30 imports is a pain to change. Having the same 30 in multiple files is an even bigger pain.

I was reading https://blog.risingstack.com/fundamental-node-js-design-patterns/ and I looked at the dependency injection area. In the example 1 dependency is passed, fine. What about *30*? I don't think that would be good practice?

How would one structure such an application with so many dependencies? And make it friendly for unit testing and mocking?

Answer (score 0):

Implements an Ioc pattern as the dependency injection is in your projects always is a very good choice, this allows you to decouple and granulate your software making it more flexible and less rigid. with the node js module patter is very hard to implements abstraction in your code, that always is required in good architectures, also, doing it, make your code meets with the D [Dependency Inversion] from SOLID and make more easy implements the S-O-I.

If you wanna see an use case for DI, see the readme for this repository also a DI library for node [Jems DI](https://github.com/JemsFramework/di), it void the long importing list in modules, and do not make you depend 100% on it with things like putting metadata or forcing you to write extra code in your modules that depend on the DI libraries or sometimes are not needed for your business logic, always you put some abstraction between that DI library and your instances activation.